# Meaning and use of 悪くないか

Tags: colloquial-language, word-usage

悪くないか

Scenario 1: a young boy comes home and says (to his sick mother)「母さん悪くないか」。

Scenario 2: two men are moving a tv and one thinks 「なんかバランス悪くないか？！」。

I’m not following the meaning of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 母さん悪くないか.

Can you let me know the exact situation?

なんかバランス悪くないか？！ can be "A bit unbalanced isn't it?!"

Comment: Apparently his mother is sick and that’s the first thing he says when he gets home

Comment: If the boy is saying (or asking) to his mother, he will probably say お母さん大丈夫か？ which is "Are you OK?".
I think you need another example.